# css: content out of span

Tags: html, css

I write a html-css demo that has two simple *span* tag. I put some content in the *span*,and use the same css code.But the content of the right *span* out of the border,the content of the left *span* in the border.

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.container{
  background-color: #5b6dcd;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:400px;
}

span{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>
    This is a box where you can change the width.
    </span>
    <span>
    o1bn-43OCWVIP2fQNVPTQ1QNQrKc
    </span>
</div>
```

[image]

[My demo project on codeopen](https://codepen.io/Q10Viking/project/editor/Dvxveq)

I'm a beginner for css,can someone please explain what happends? **Why the right one out of border**?Thank you for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your style css to span this

```
span {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Because it is a long line of text and browser can split it by word, as in the first span

Answer (score 1):

The text is overflowing because there are no spaces in the text to break onto a new line.

You can solve this by using `word-break: break-all;` which will break in the middle of a "word".